# Is OAuth2 Token request from DocuSign OAuth (Resource Owner Credentials or SAML) still be supported in new REST API?

Tags: docusignapi

Is the OAuth2 Authentication method given [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/OAuth2%20Token%20Request.htm%3FTocPath%3DDocuSign%2520OAuth%2520(Resource%2520Owner%2520Credentials%2520or%2520SAML)%7C_____2) still supported? Is there any plan to deprecate this?

The above link is from older REST API documentation and the same method is not given on new REST API documentation.

I have signed up for a free trial account and have no paid account to get support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Authentication method is deprecated, and will phase out in future. You can check current recommended approach at [DS Authentication Overview](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html)

Comment: You mention that it "might phase out in future". Will it actually phase out ? If yes, any ETA on when ? 1 week ? 1 month? 1 year ?

Comment: There is no ETA as of now. But main point is no new integration should use these old ways, they all should move to new OAUTH way as documented in DS Docs.

Comment: Has it mentioned on DocuSign page somewhere? or been officially said not to use this method?

Comment: Since its been obsolete/deprecated, that's the main reason why this approach is not available in our new documentation link docs.docusign.com. And what needs to used are available in the link shared in my answer.

Comment: @AmitKBist - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Amit is correct. New integrations should not use that method, it has been deprecated. That method is in the current documentation, see [Authentication::getOAuthToken](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Authentication/Authentication/getOAuthToken)

It is marked as **Deprecated**. The exact phase-out schedule has not been decided yet.

DocuSign supports OAuth2 through a new set of API calls. See [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication).

Comment: Has it mentioned on DocuSign page somewhere? or been officially said not to use this method?

Comment: Please see the page [Authentication::getOAuthToken](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Authentication/Authentication/getOAuthToken). The method is marked as deprecated in the current documentation.

Comment: But that says for SDK. And not for REST API, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Sorry, you are mistaken. That page is for the eSignature REST API itself.

Comment: Sorry. Is eSignature REST API same as new API for DocuSign? whatever limitations given for eSignature REST API applied to DocuSign new REST API? I might be silly here as I am not sure about eSignature API's and I'm just going through it to understand.

Comment: DocuSign has two primary APIs: eSignature REST API and eSignature SOAP API. There are also APIs for the DocuSign Signature Appliance.